# Unable to insert floats as range_keys in DynamoDB with Boto

Tags: python, boto, amazon-dynamodb

When I attempt to insert a range_key that contains a number of more than 2 decimal places, the number stored in the database is truncated to the first 2 decimals.

How do I get around this?

```
    max_number = 1000000.0
    random_time = random.randrange(1, max_number-1) / max_number
    range_key = int(time.time()) + random_time
    data['item_id'] = '12345'
    result = db.add(table='media', key=group_id,
                    range_key = range_key,
                    data=data)
```

The resulting range_key of "1347053744.819199" gets inserted as "1347053744.82"

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

This is actually a bug in boto, see https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/890#issuecomment-8456495 for tracking

ORIGINAL ANSWER:

Why are you using `add` to store a new item ? `add` is the function for atomic increments. You should use `put_item` instead.

I do not know why your float is rounded but anyway, you really should not try it. It is a bad practice to use float as keys. It is impossible to reliably check floats equality because they are inherently approximation. see http://www.cygnus-software.com/papers/comparingfloats/comparingfloats.html for in depth insight on floats.

Nonetheless, if you *really* need floats as keys, you need to fully control there representation so as not to be dependent of the server-side implementation when de-serializing the JSON of the request. You need to replace it by a regular string.

Comment: add() is a function from a wrapper class that I wrote. It's basically put_item. Can I use the comparison operators if the range_key is a string?

Comment: Yes, all of them. Including the powerful "BEGINS_WITH". http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/API_Query.html

Comment: You're true, this is a bug in boto: https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/890#issuecomment-8456495